# travis-ci R suggested package

Tags: r, travis-ci, devtools

In my R package I have few suggested packages which I'm using in examples. Such as ROracle, RPostgreSQL, RODBC. Keeping them in suggests allows to skip testing of them, but it doesn't seems to work on travis-ci - recent `language: r`.

I tried multiple cases:
`env: _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_=false`

`env:
 global:
  - _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_=false`

Nothing helps, my package tries to install suggested packages besides what the option I've set, and that results build error. Kind of:

```
** package ‘ROracle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: error: OCI libraries not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ROracle’
1: In utils::install.packages(deps, dependencies = NA, Ncpus = threads) :
  installation of package ‘RODBC’ had non-zero exit status
2: In utils::install.packages(deps, dependencies = NA, Ncpus = threads) :
  installation of package ‘ROracle’ had non-zero exit status
The command "Rscript -e 'options(repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com"); tryCatch({   deps <- devtools::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE) }, error = function(e) {   message(e);   q(status=1) }); if (!all(deps %in% installed.packages())) {  q(status = 1, save = "no") }'" failed and exited with 1 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

**Any easy way to avoid installing postgres, oracle, odbc and still use native travis?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That changed a while back in R itself, and packages in `Suggests:` now need to be present when running `R CMD check`. A total pain as it worked before, but so it is...

Now, for two of these you are in luck as you can do

```
install_aptget r-cran-rodbc r-cran-rpostgresql
```

but for ROracle you will have to install the package from source (or alter your `Suggests:`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, this is a total pain, I will remove ROracle from examples.
PS. `devtools::check(force_suggests=FALSE)` still works in `1.7.0`. That may be useful for non travis users.

Comment: Well _if_ `devtools` can do it reliably maybe there is a setting. Do you want to try setting more environment variables as it does?  Whenever I tried (and I have a fair number of Travis projects) I failed miserably and ended up either installing all `Suggests:` or reducing/removing them you suggest here.

Comment: Forget to mention, `check(force_suggests=FALSE)` works on `3.1.2` so it might not be up to date with `3.1.3`.
Anyway if this is the direction of package dev standards/checks I will follow and reduce suggests. Hope it will let me create vignette with `eval=FALSE` chunks and put examples there. Thanks

Comment: You need to translate it into a pure `R CMD check` invocation. I don't use `devtools`.  But the R change occurred (IIRC) before 3.1.2.

Comment: it seems to working already: `R CMD check pkg_0.1.tar.gz --no-manual` > `* checking package dependencies ... NOTE
Package which this enhances but not available for checking: ‘asdasd’`

Comment: Started using travis-ci only a while ago and stumbled across the same problem. And seems like I don't really understand the solution here ;-) Could you tell me what I need to do in order to have travis-ci not complaining about my packages in `Suggests` when automatically triggering it via GitHub commits?